# Xamarin.Android UI not displaying appropriately on run time as it does while Android Designer

Tags: c#, xml, xamarin, xamarin.android

I made a Layout File and added different kinds of views and adjusted them using `Layout - ViewGroup` and `Layout - RelativeLayout` properties. The images and icons that I'm using were made for mdpi by a graphic designer. The runtime display doesn't match the one in the desinger mode. Since I am positioning the UI elements based on the element above it, the resulting elements shift downwards and some aren't even visible on the screen.

I tried aligning using `Layout - RelativeLayout` both with the element above and below the current element and then adjust margin using `Layout - ViewGroup` properties but I couldn't do the later because the element got stretched even though I set `Layout Height` and `Layout Width` to `wrap_content`.

Here's the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:id="@+id/imageViewLoginBG"
        android:src="@drawable/loginbg"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/loginlogo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageViewLoginLogo"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp" />
    <EditText
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editTextLoginEmail"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewLoginLogo"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0.0dp"
        android:layout_width="300.0dp"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
    <EditText
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:layout_width="300.0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editTextLoginPass"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextLoginEmail"
        android:layout_marginTop="15.0dp" />
    <ImageButton
        android:src="@drawable/loginbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageButtonLogin"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextLoginPass"
        android:layout_marginTop="45.0dp" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Don't have an account? Register Now"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textViewLoginReg"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageViewLoginBG"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10.0dp"
        android:textColor="#fffafafa"
        android:textSize="12sp"/>
    <TextView
        android:text="Forgot Password?"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textViewLoginFrgPass"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0.0dp"
        android:textColor="#fffafafa"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageButtonLogin"
        android:layout_marginTop="10.0dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is how the layout looks in the designer:
https://ibb.co/YLn3X4g
This is what it looks like in an emulator:
https://ibb.co/4wyDB9D

Note: Even the action bar gets displayed!?

Comment: Please create a emulator base device with Nexus 4 like this screenshot.https://imgur.com/a/pD9NlwQ  ,I notice your designer based on the device is  Nexus 4

Comment: I'm assuming from your response that the emulator that I am using has different dpi's then the one I am designing the interface for (mdpi). So if the emulator I run the app on has mpdi but a different screen size than Nexus 4 would the same problem still persist? @LeonLu-MSFT
And why is the action bar being displayed even though the theme is set to NoActionBar